# Migrating from Parse to Firebase Push Notifications on IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, notifications, push, migrating

I am using the Parse demo app (ParseStarterProject) and Firebase demo app (Messaging Example) 
Both using the same Bundle Identifier  and GoogleService-Info.plist

I checked first that they were receiving pushes , installing them separately one at a time and using postman to send them messages
Then I freshly installed the Parse Demo app and subscribe to a channel
Once I received a push notification from parse I install the Firebase demo app (Messaging Example) and subscribe to a topic

FIRMessaging registration is not ready with auth credentials
2016-12-13 19:42:25.648:  Failed to subscribe to topic Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=501 "(null)"

+-70% of the time the app fails to get the firebase push after the migration

Any info on solving this issue will be greatly appreciated

Comment: That looks like a configuration issue but without code it would be hard to tell.

Comment: Problem Solved it was the APNs certificates were the same on Parse and FCM I added a new one to FCM and no more problems